# What is the best way to implement a double-ended priority queue?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, big-o, priority-queue, heapsort

I would like to implement a double-ended priority queue with the following constraints:

- needs to be implemented in a fixed size array..say 100 elements..if new elements need to be added after the array is full, the oldest needs to be removed
- need maximum and minimum in O(1)
- if possible insert in O(1)
- if possible remove minimum in O(1)
- clear to empty/init state in O(1) if possible
- count of number of elements in array at the moment in O(1)

I would like O(1) for all the above 5 operations but its not possible to have O(1) on all of them in the same implementation. Atleast O(1) on 3 operations and O(log(n)) on the other 2 operations should suffice.

Will appreciate if any pointers can be provided to such an implementation.

Comment: have you tried anything? at least clear to empty/init state in O(1) is more than trivial to one who knows about basic data structure :(

Comment: @Fallen ya even the count too..just keep track of it...I am just making the operations and time complexities explicit :), so someone suggesting a particular implementation will have clear idea of expectations

Comment: Well, you can't have insert *and* extract minimum/maximum be constant or amortized constant time, because that would imply a linear time sorting algorithm. All assuming your keys aren't integers or such but black boxes with comparison operators.

Answer (score 5):

There are many specialized data structures for this.  One simple data structure is the min-max heap, which is implemented as a binary heap where the layers alternate between "min layers" (each node is less than or equal to its descendants) and "max layers" (each node is greater than or equal to its descendants.)  The minimum and maximum can be found in time O(1), and, as in a standard binary heap, enqueues and dequeues can be done in time O(log n) time each.

You can also use the [interval heap data structure](http://keithschwarz.com/interesting/code/?dir=interval-heap), which is another specialized priority queue for the task.

Alternatively, you can use two priority queues - one storing elements in ascending order and one in descending order.  Whenever you insert a value, you can then insert elements into both priority queues and have each store a pointer to the other.  Then, whenever you dequeue the min or max, you can remove the corresponding element from the other heap.

As yet another option, you could use a balanced binary search tree to store the elements.  The minimum and maximum can then be found in time O(log n) (or O(1) if you cache the results) and insertions and deletions can be done in time O(log n).  If you're using C++, you can just use `std::map` for this and then use `begin()` and `rbegin()` to get the minimum and maximum values, respectively.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks, greatest help required would be a clean implementation of min-max heap in C or C++

Comment: @Medicine- I updated my answer with several other solutions.  The last one addresses a simple C++ idea.

Answer (score 2):

A [binary heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap) will give you insert and remove minimum in `O(log n)` and the others in `O(1)`.

The only tricky part is removing the oldest element once the array is full. For this, keep another array:

```
time[i] = at what position in the heap array is the element 
          added at time i + 100 * k.
```

Every 100 iterations, you increment `k`.

Then, when the array fills up for the first time, you remove `heap[ time[0] ]`, when it fills up for the second time you remove `heap[ time[1] ]`, ..., when it fills up for the 100th time, you wrap around and remove `heap[ time[0] ]` again etc. When it fills up for the `k`th time, you remove `heap[ time[k % 100] ]` (100 is your array size).

Make sure to also update the `time` array when you insert and remove elements.

Removal of an arbitrary element can be done in `O(log n)` if you know its position: just swap it with the last element in your heap array, and sift down the element you have swapped in.

Comment: how can we find both min and max from a binary heap in O(1), I thought we can only find one of them in O(1) depending on its a min or max heap.

Comment: @Medicine - keep two heaps, or see templatetypedef's answer.

Comment: ok so to remove min..I can remove in O(log(n)) from min heap..what extra effort is required to remove the same element from max heap

Comment: @Medicine - the same, `O(log n)`. `2*O(log n) = O(log n)`. You can see where an element in one is in the other by keeping arrays similar to `time`. It's probably less work if you use a min-max heap however.

Comment: was thinking of a minmax heap but need a reference implementation

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely need max and min to be O(1) then what you can do is create a linked list, where you constantly keep track of min, max, and size, and then link all the nodes to some sort of tree structure, probably a heap. Min, max, and size would all be constant, and since finding any node would be in O(log n), insert and remove are log n each. Clearing would be trivial.

Answer (score -1):

If your queue is a fixed size, then O-notation is meaningless. Any O(log n) or even O(n) operation is essentially O(1) because n is fixed, so what you really want is an algorithm that's fast for the given dataset. Probably two parallel traditional heap priority queues would be fine (one for high, one for low).

If you know more about what kind of data you have, you might be able to make something more special-purpose.